# How to create trigger after UPDATE in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, database-trigger

I have tables `Room Details`:

[image]

and `Log Room Status`:

[image]

I want to create a trigger where when in the `room details` table I change the `status` column then in the `log room status` table in the `status` column before and after the status will automatically change. For example when in `Room Details` the status is `Vacant Dirty` and I change it to `Vacant Clean`, then the log room status in the Before status column will be filled with **Vacant Dirty** and after status will be filled with **Vacant Clean**

Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.log_rs_history()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$DECLARE

BEGIN
IF status = 'UPDATE' THEN
UPDATE log_room_status set status_before=old.status_before, status_after=new.status_after where id_room=id_room and room_number=room_number;
      END IF;
  RETURN new;
END$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;

  CREATE TRIGGER log_history
  AFTER UPDATE
  ON public.room_details
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.product_hs_history();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close.  I think you meant to do this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.log_rs_history()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
IF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
  UPDATE log_room_status
     SET status_before=old.status,
         status_after=new.status
   WHERE id_room=new.id_room
     AND room_number=new.room_number;
  END IF;
  RETURN new;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;

CREATE TRIGGER log_history
  AFTER UPDATE
  ON public.room_details
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.log_rs_history();
```